# Effect of freeing memory of a process that isn't assigned memory in the Buddy Memory Allocation Method

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free, memo

I'm doing a practical example of the Buddy Memory Allocation Method and I stumbled upon a step that I'm confused by. The following is an example of the memory and its allocated sections.

```
--------------------------------
|               |              |
|     a1        |       a2     |
|               |              |
--------------------------------
```

What happens if now I have `free(a3);`? Since `a3` is not even in any of the blocks, do we just ignore it?

Comment: Normally you require that the user should only free pointers that were returned by your malloc and have not already been freed.  If they do otherwise, you're not responsible for the consequences, and so you can assume it never happens.  If your algorithm makes it easy for you to detect this, you can print an error message or call `abort()` or whatever you think would help in debugging, but that's a convenience feature, not a requirement.

Comment: But if this is for an exercise, there's no way for us to know what your teacher is expecting; you should ask them.

Comment: I guess I omitted a relevant exception: the user may also `free` a null pointer.  In this case `free` should return without doing anything, so you can simply put `if (p == NULL) return;` in your `free` function.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, on how the algorithm is implemented. If the implementation doesn't check, whether this is a valid pointer, it can corrupt the internal state leading to subtle and hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: Hmm .. the problem is that, this is an exercise question and it doesn't mention anything else other than the fact that it's the Buddy Memory Allocation Method and that we have xxMB of free memory in the beginning. Step by step you have to fill the memory and show that in a diagram.

Comment: The question also had the command: a3 = malloc(12MB); followed by free(a3);. Since there is no space available, I skipped the step of allocating memory to a3. This, however, also meant that I would skip freeing the memory, since I never allocated it.

Comment: @SkiMask: If you failed to allocate 12 MB, then you should have returned NULL, and so `free(a3)` is just freeing a NULL pointer.  The C standard requires that `free(NULL)` is legal and does nothing, so that's what you should do.

Comment: Ok, normally `malloc` returns `NULL`, if there is an error like no available memory. And `free` ignores, if a null pointer is passed to it."If ptr is a null pointer, the function does nothing." (https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

Comment: So if it returns NULL, then if I were to draw the diagram in the question after the free(a3) step, it would look exactly the same as the one above, correct?

Comment: Yes, because you didn't allocate any memory.

Comment: Yes, as `free` ignores NULL.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!